# Jquery add variable to back button

Tags: jquery, ajax, button, back

I have an AJAX call on a page, that uses some variables from url at page load.

```
www.myurl.com/?mayvar=foo
```

These variables can be changed before user goes to next page. For example user checks a checkbox, and I got new variable.

```
mynewwar=bar
```

How can I make a back button to lead to a new address

```
www.myurl.com/?mayvar=foo&mynewwar=bar
```

if user wants to go back?

Comment: when a user checks a checkbox, does it also change the url to include the variable?

Comment: if user ckecks a ckeckbox, it initialises new ajax call with nwe vars,  new content loads but url (in address bar) stays the same.

Comment: do you mean the browser's back button, or a custom back button?  And you want to navigate one data set back correct?

Comment: http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

Comment: i use both browser and custom back button. Custom back button is not a problem, i just handle click event and sent new variables to new page and then send it back with click on custom button. But browser back button is a problem

Comment: also check http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/state/portfolio

Comment: i think, the only thing I need is document.location.hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the variables in hash:

```
var variable = 'mayvar=foo&mynewvar=bar';
location.hash = variable;
```

this will change the url without going out of the page, and the back button will remember 
the past hashes (of course you'll have to change your script accordingly to read from the hash)